# why select statement take more time to fetch records from remote mysql server rather than server on localhost

Tags: mysql

here is my table desc.

```
| Field       | Type       | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| user_id     | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       |
| friend_id   | bigint(20) | NO   | PRI | NULL                |       |
| to_status   | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | 0                   |       |
| from_status | tinyint(1) | YES  |     | 0                   |       |
| match_date  | timestamp  | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
+-------------+------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
```

and it has more then 320000 records. so when i select row as `select *from friend where to_status=1 and from_status=1`

then

1. from local it takes 1.2s
2. and from remote server it takes something about 5.4sec

Why it taking time longer when same table on both system (my local and remote)

Comment: Is the remote server configuration same as the local?

Comment: Because the network to the remote server is slower than TCP/IP within the localhost.

Comment: Yes both configured same

Comment: They're not the same. Communication within the local host takes place at bus speeds. Communication with remote server takes place at Ethernet speeds, or a Internet speeds if it's remote enough. These are all orders of magnitude different.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case of local machine code server and database both are in the same environment and it doesn't need internet connection. And in case of  remote connection your code server and database server both are placed in different environment (causes of increases in response time is round trip/travel time).
So obviously it'll take some extra time as compare to local. Also in case of  remote communication it is depends upon internet connection speed these are the factors to goes slowdown response of remote communication as compare to local.